# Simple way to multiply column elements by corresponding vector elements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to multiply every column of a M × N matrix by corresponding element of a vector of size N.

I know it's possible using a for loop. But I'm seeking a more simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
mat1=randi(10,[4 5]);
vec1=randi(10,[1 5]);
result=mat1.*repmat(vec1,[size(mat1,1),1]);
```

`rempat` will replicate `vec1` along the rows of `mat1`. Then we can do element-wise multiplication `(.*)` to "multiply every column of a `M × N` matrix by corresponding element of a vector of size `N`".

**Edit**: Just to add to the computational aspect. There is an alternative to `repmat` that I would like you to know. Matrix indexing can achieve the same behavior as `repmat` and be faster. I have adopted this technique from [here](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/research/matlabindexrepmat.html).

Observe that you can write the following statement

```
repmat(vec1,[size(mat1,1),1]);
```

as

```
vec1([1:size(vec1,1)]'*ones(1,size(mat1,1)),:);
```

If you see closely, the expression boils down to `vec1([1]'*[1 1 1 1]),:);` which is again:

```
vec1([1 1 1 1]),:);
```

thereby achieving the same behavior as `repmat` and be faster. I ran three solutions `100000` times, namely,

1. Solution using `repmat` : 0.824518 seconds
2. Solution using indexing technique explained above : 0.734435 seconds
3. Solution using `bsxfun` provided by [@LuisMendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811427/1586200) : 0.683331 seconds

You can observe that `bsxfun` is slightly faster.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, `bsxfun` is the fastest method.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can do it with `repmat` (as in [@Parag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21810032/2586922)), it's often [more efficient](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) to use  [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). It also has the advantage that the code (last line) is the same for a row and for a column vector.

```
%// Example data
M = 4;
N = 5;
matrix = rand(M,N);
vector = rand(1,N); %// or size M,1

%// Computation
result = bsxfun(@times, matrix, vector); %// bsxfun does an "implicit" repmat
```

Comment: if bsxfun does an "implicit" repmat, where is the efficiency?

Comment: @SAM See [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/). My guess is that `bsxfun` "knows" the elements are the same so internally it doesn't replicate them as `repmat` does